# How to add comment with git SHA during Webpack build?

Tags: javascript, html, git, webpack

I want to insert a comment into `<head>` during build:

`<!-- SHA: xxxx -->`

I get required data using this:

```
const revision = child_process
  .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD')
  .toString().trim()
```

but I have no idea how to put it inside `index.html` file. I tried `html-webpack-plugin` and passing it like this:

```
HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  minify: minifyOptions,
  template: "public/index.html",
  templateParameters: {
    publicPath,
    revision,
  },
})
```

and then adding this into `<head>` in `index.html`:
`<%= <!-- SHA: revision --> %>`

but then Webpack build fails (it looks like it can't parse HTML comments). I can't even put it as something inside `<comment>` tags because it automatically gets moved to `<body>`. Is this possible to inject comments into HTML with Webpack?

Comment: `<%= <!-- SHA: revision --> %>` is not valid ejs, perhaps you just need to make it a string `<%= '<!-- SHA: '+revision+' -->' %>`

Comment: Yes, I know that - the question is, how can I make it valid? Is there any way to somehow "escape" that HTML comment and make it appear in built file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there is very easy workaround for this. We can just pass whole comment as parameter, like this:

```
HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  minify: minifyOptions,
  template: "public/index.html",
  templateParameters: {
    publicPath,
    gitInfo: `<!-- SHA: ${commitHash} | BRANCH: ${branch} -->`,
  },
}),
```

(Remember that you have to set `removeComments` to false in `minifyOptions` of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`)

and then reference it in `index.html` like this:

```
<%= gitInfo %>
```